# Split posts into 2 separate streams

Tags: categories, tags

I have a blog of my travels during an adventure in India from last year (it is an *amazing* place!).  I am about to head back on another trip and would like to use the same blog.

However I would like to keep last year's trip separate from this year's somehow.

I have tagged all last year *2015*, is there a way to do something like only show *2016* posts as the default home page and have a link to *2015* posts in the menu or somewhere?

Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: So right now your homepage is showing all of your posts?

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan Correct.  I want to keep all those posts as an archive and start the home page afresh...and blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following

- You are using WP default *Post* type
- When you say *tagged* you mean you used *categories* and not the *tag* system
- You have at least the following categories 2015 and 2016, and that you have categorized all of your posts accordingly
- You are using the default blogroll of WP

If I assumed wrong about your setup maybe this will need adjustments, but you can definitely filter what's showing up in your blogroll.  You would need to modify WP Query for that. (I'll give an example below)

But before messing around with queries, you would need to create a menu and select the categories you wish to add to your menu.
This is done in **Appearance -> Menus -> Categories**

These categories would be your *archives* so make sure you categorize those well or you will miss some post later on (not lost, just hidden).

By categorizing each post, you would have an archive of your post, filtered by the category(ies) they are in.

So now you want a clean blogroll. To achieve that we need to modify the main query.

This is how you can do it.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_blog' );
function my_custom_blog( $wp_query ){

  if( is_home() ){ // Our custom query will affect only the blogroll

    $wp_query->set( 'category_name', '2016' ); // category name is the slug of the category

  }
}
```

This will effectively remove everything from your blog roll and only show posts that are ***in*** the category *2016*. So if your category is empty, nothing will show.

Let's say next year you have another trip, you just categorize your future posts *2017* and change your query `category_name` for `2017`. Then you would add another link to your menu. This link would be for the category 2016.

Comment: Perfect!  I edited  for clarity that the place to add the code is in functions.php.

Comment: Seems my edit was rejected.  Can't understand why :P